# Application crashes when calling invalidateLayout method in iOS 9

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I want to update `UICollectionView` layout every minute. It works well in iOS 10 but it crashes in iOS 9 (I tested it in iPad 2) 
`invalidateLayout` method makes `UICollectionView` update. and it crashes when calling this method.

```
    override init() {
        super.init()
        initializeMinuteTick()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    deinit {
        minuteTimer?.invalidate()
    }

    private func initializeMinuteTick() {
        guard let validDate = Date().addMinute(num: 1) else { return }

        minuteTimer = Timer(fireAt: validDate, interval: TimeInterval(60), target: self, selector: #selector(minuteTick), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

        if let minuteTimer = minuteTimer {
            RunLoop.current.add(minuteTimer, forMode: .defaultRunLoopMode)
        }
    }

    func minuteTick() {
        cachedCurrentTimeComponents.removeAll()

        // CRASH ----------------
        invalidateLayout()
        // CRASH ----------------
    }
```

Error:

> Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Comment: If it crashes, then perhaps you can include the error message? And a body of the function that makes it crash?

Comment: @mag_zbc Thanks. I added it.

Comment: And the body of `invalidateLayout`? What class is that anyway, is it your view controller, or is it a `UICollectionViewLayout` subclass? You provided next to nothing, for anyone to help you you need to show at least minimum effort.

Comment: @mag_zbc Thanks, Its one of the UICollectionViewLayout methods.

Answer (score 0):

Try calling `reloadData()` on the `collectionView`. Also make sure that `dataSource` for the `collectionView` is already filled with data before calling the reloading functions (maybe there is a place where you force unwrap a value?).

Comment: Thanks. when I called  "collectionView?.reloadData()" it crashed at reload line. But if dataSource is not ready why it works in iOS 10?